# Autcomplete and Multiple values in Framework7

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 for my Cordova app.
Autocomplete is a very powerful feature of Framework7 and I'm trying to use it:

https://framework7.io/docs/autocomplete.html

On my app the user should be able to select multiple items from a list of given options, with autocomplete. The user should also be able to add new items to the list

The closest feature I found is "multiple values" but unfortunately it doesn't allow the user to add more items

[image]

How can I let the user add items to the list while searching and selecting them?

If such feature doesn't exist I'm willing to build it on my own using the Framework7 components... in that case I just need some UX advice on how to do it properly